# How to add legend label in python animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting data (count) from database usling Matplotlib/Python. I cannot figure out how to have an animated legend. I want the legend to display the current value of the line.

The code is:

```
def db_count():
    ### Connect to db and run query ...
    return count

x_data, y_data = [], []
figure = plt.figure()
count = db_count()
line, = plt.plot_date(x_data, y_data, '-', label=count)

def update(frame):
    x_data.append(datetime.now())
    count = db_count()
    y_data.append(count)
    line.set_data(x_data, y_data)
    figure.gca().autoscale_view()
    figure.gca().relim()
    return line,

animation = FuncAnimation(figure, update, interval=60000)

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Counts')
plt.title('Total counts')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0.05))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the label of your line in the `update` function using `line.set_label(count)`, then call `plt.legend()`:

```
def db_count():
    ### Connect to db and run query ...
    return count

x_data, y_data = [], []
figure = plt.figure()
count = db_count()
line, = plt.plot_date(x_data, y_data, '-', label=count)

def update(frame):
    x_data.append(datetime.now())
    count = db_count()
    y_data.append(count)
    line.set_data(x_data, y_data)

    line.set_label(count) # set the label and draw the legend
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0.05))

    figure.gca().autoscale_view()
    figure.gca().relim()
    return line,

animation = FuncAnimation(figure, update, interval=60000)

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Counts')
plt.title('Total counts')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Comment: @Igor No problem. If an answer helped you then can vote and/or accept it if you wish, as described in [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)